# backbone error while trying to reset a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am doing a very simple Backbone app example and I keep getting a JS error message. I basically have two files:

1. app.js

This file creates a Backbone.js app the appends a span from a template using data from a collection view to an already created div on the html file.

```
    /*Backbone.js Appointments App*/

    App = (function($){
      //Create Appointment Model
      var Appointment = Backbone.Model.extend({});

      //Create Appointments Collection
      var Appointments = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Appointment
      });

      //Instantiate Appointments Collection
      var appointmentList = new Appointments();
      appointmentList.reset(
        [{startDate: '2013-01-11', title: 'First Appointment', description: 'None', id: 1},
         {startDate: '2013-02-21', title: 'Second Appointment', description: 'None', id: 2},
         {startDate: '2013-02-26', title: 'Third Appointment', description: 'None', id: 3}
        ]
      );

      //Create Appointment View
      var AppointmentView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template(
          '<span class="appointment" title="<%= description %>">' +
          ' <span class="title"><%= title %></span>' +
          ' <span class="delete">X</span>' +
          '</span>'
        ),

        initialize: function(options) {
          this.container = $('#container');
        },

        render: function() {
          $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model));
          this.container.append(this.el);
          return this;
        }
      });

      var self = {};
      self.start = function(){
        new AppointmentView({collection: appointmentList}).render();
      };
      return self;
    });

    $(function(){
      new App(jQuery).start();
    });
```

1. index.html

This file just calls the jquery, backbone and other js libraries and also created the div container where the Backbone.js app from the previous file will append the data.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>hello-backbonejs</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'reset' app.js:14
App app.js:14
(anonymous function) app.js:49
e.resolveWith jquery.min.js:16
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:16
c.addEventListener.z jquery.min.js:16
```

Answer (score 2):

You use Backbone 0.3.3 but `Collection.reset` was introduced in Backbone 0.5. See the [changelog](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog) for more information.

Either upgrade Backbone (0.9.9 at the moment) (and Underscore and jQuery while you're at it) or use `Collection#refresh` if you absolutely have to keep Backbone 0.3.3 (but you will probably trip other errors down the road).